# Can SublimeJEDI autocomplete custom/external class instances?

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, sublimetext3

For example:

```
from PIL import Image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    im =Image.open("room.tif")
    Image.Image.
```

when my cursor is at the dot after `Image.Image.` and I press Ctrl+Space it will show the following:
[image]

However, if I type `im.` and press Ctrl+Space it will show nothing. Why does SublimeJEDI not recognize that im is also an `Image.Image` object instance? Have I configured it wrongly? Is there another plugin/IDE that can do this? SublimeCodeIntel can't, SublimePythonIDE either (in my limited experience).

**Edit:**
It seems that both Atom (autocomplete-python-jedi-plus) and SublimeText (SublimeJEDI) are capable of doing this with builtin types, but not with external packages (e.g. *Pillow* in this *case*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mailed the SublimePythonIDE dev with this question and got the following response:

> Hi,
>
> SublimePythonIDE internally uses the Jedi library, so there shouldn’t
>   be much difference to SublimeJedi or Anaconda in this regard. Remember
>   that Python is dynamically typed, so completion is really hard to do
>   in general, and requires some form of type inference. If Jedi can
>   infer the type of the variable, then yes. Whether Jedi can do it
>   depends on many factors, and there is no general answer.
>
> So, all in all, the is answer is: sometimes :-)